# Match two arrays with same id

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

```js
const array1 = [{id:1,name: "foo"},{id:2,name:"boo"},{id:3,name:"fob"}]
const array2 = [{id:1, carType: "truck"},{id:2, carType: "sedan"},{id:3,carType: "suv"}]
```

How to push name from array1 to array2 with matching ids

end result

```js
array3 = [
{id:1, carType: "truck",name: "foo"},
{id:2, carType: "sedan", name: "boo"},
{id:3,carType: "suv",name:"fob"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
const array1 = [{id:1,name: "foo"},{id:2,name:"boo"},{id:3,name:"fob"}]
const array2 = [{id:1, carType: "truck"},{id:2, carType: "sedan"},{id:3,carType: "suv"}]


const indexed = Object.fromEntries(array1.map(o => [o.id, o]))

const combined = array2.map(o => ({...o, ...indexed[o.id]}))

console.log(combined)
```

i.e. create an object out of one of the arrays, using the id as the key. Then you can map over the 2nd one and use the 'index' to quickly look up elements in the first one.

Comment: I like the flexibility of this one. It handles properties other than just `name`

Comment: nice, it merges all props. thanks

Comment: What about if i'm only interested in merging specific props, for example in this case, if array 1 had name, X, Y, Z props but i only wanted name and X prop to merge.

Comment: Replacing `const combined = array2.map(o => ({...o, ...indexed[o.id]}))` with `const combined = array2.map(o => ({...o, name: indexed[o.id].name, x: indexed[o.id].x}))` will answer my previous comment.